# RabbitMQ with Python - How to consume asynchronously (in the background)?

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

Currently I am trying to consume from my queue while I service other tasks - parallel computation, if you will.

I'd like to have my queue consuming "requests" while my program simultaneously does its computations.

For example, if my code calculates the Fibonacci sequence for a request, currently, I can send several requests but they are not "received" till the fibonacci calculation for the former request is complete.

So my question is, how can I consume "in the background" while my program executes? Is there a Pika/RabbitMQ methodology to achieve this? Or is my best bet threads or multiprocessing?

Thanks

Comment: http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html --> you can fire something like this up in a separate thread and communicate between the two threads using a threadsafe queue.

Comment: You can do something like this https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/tree/master/Flask-examples